# How to put the abstract on the same page as the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, abstract

For a report in LaTeX I would like to position the abstract before the table of contents. Is it possible for the Table of Contents to start straight after the Abstract on the same page (at the moment the Table of Contents starts on the next page)?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\section*{Abstract}

\tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @campa I have added a minimal working example now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\tableofcontents` automatically adds a `\clearpage` command. To remove this, replace it with `{\let\clearpage\relax \tableofcontents}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\begin{document}
\section*{abstract}

{\let\clearpage\relax \tableofcontents} 
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```