# title and abstract and table of contents in the same page

Tags: page-breaking

i'm trying to prevent a page break between the abstract and the table of contents everytime i compile i get a page break right after the end of the abstract.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,onecolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,amsmath,bbm,bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{Marouane}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
the content of the abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
```

i get a page-break after that and then the table of contents starts in a new page, which is something that i don't want i want the table of contents right after the abstract

Comment: Welcome. Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544882/how-to-put-the-abstract-on-the-same-page-as-the-table-of-contents

Answer (score 1):

To remove the page-break before the table of contents, you need to replace `\tableofcontents` with `{\let\clearpage\relax \tableofcontents}`. But as it stands, you still have the title page in between the abstract and the table of contents, which also starts a new page.